# Regex for beginning of line -or- last number in sentance

Tags: c#, regex, string-search

```
new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z]+\b +\b[a-zA-Z]?\b +\b[a-zA-Z]+$")
```

this matches

`John Smith`
`John B Goode`

I am trying to modify this regex for the following cases:

some text before `12359 (John B? Goode) 10249?`

that is sometimes the name comes after the a number at the end of the string and optionally before a final number at the end.

I have tried

```
new Regex(@"^|[0-9]+([a-zA-Z]+\b +\b[a-zA-Z]?\b +\b[a-zA-Z]+) *[0-9]*?$")
```

but that does not work because

1. the `^|[0-9]+` only matches numbers anymore and not beginning of line
2. the group is always an empty string that match something like `sometext 12354` (the first number needs to not be at the end of a line.

**Update**

This is all water under the bridge because I found more names at the end of the lines of data so this will not work.

However the solution to my problem was not throwing the OR in a group.

Comment: −1 for specifying the regex tag but not specifying the programming language tag. Fix that and I’ll remove my downvote.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Give four or five examples of strings you want to match, and which part you want to capture. Also give four or five examples that you want to not match.

Comment: I'm guessing the programming language is C#.

Comment: @MarkByers Yeah, really. Pretty sure all strings match any pattern that starts like `^|........`.

Comment: @tchrist tag was updated, I'm here to please.

Comment: There you go, two for the price of one. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need parentheses around the alternation:

```
(^|[0-9]+)
```

Your expression is equivalent to this:

```
new Regex(@"^|()")
```

It always matches the start of the string and nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

*Edit (re Alan Moore's info)*

Another try. The problem statement is unclear as to if you're going for a *FULL* valdation or just trying to extract the name, validating just the surrounding extraction.

If attempting a %100 validation extraction, then you *should* be concerned about the BOL.
Otherwise, you only need to worry about the EOL.

For %100 validation:

```
(?:^|[0-9]+\ +)([a-zA-Z]+\ +(?:[a-zA-Z]\ +)?[a-zA-Z]+)(?:\ +[0-9]+)?$
```

Expanded:

```
(?:  ^              # BOL
   | [0-9]+ \ +     # or, leading numbers + space
)
(                      # Capt 1
   [a-zA-Z]+               # first name
   \ +                     # space
   (?: [a-zA-Z] \ + )?     # optional middle initial + space
   [a-zA-Z]+               # last name
)                      # End Capt 1
(?: \ + [0-9]+ )?      # optional space + trailing numbers
$                   # EOL
```

Or, if you just want to extract the text, only the EOL anchor is needed and some restrictions can be loosened:

```
\b([a-zA-Z](?:\s+[a-zA-Z.]+)*)[\s\d]*$
```

Comment: +1 for handling the optional parts correctly and getting rid of the unneeded word boundaries.  But I think the match is supposed to start with **either** the BOL **or** a number, as @Mark demonstrated.

Comment: Oh, you know, I didn't read that into it, thought the OP was just trying to extract from a `number? name number?` form. Where `^$` was needed in my original form. *If* its just for matching the name at the end, the EOL anchor is really all that is needed, not the BOL.